# Removing multiple commas with a single comma in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Want to remove multiple commas [with or without spaces] with a single one. Tried this regex however it failed `preg_replace("/\s{1,5},\s{1,5}+/", ", ", $string);`
Tried other solutions but can't find any solution where space also exists with comma.

**Sample input**

```
GUWAHATI, TEZPUR, , BAMUNI HILLS, MAHABHAIRAB TEMPLE, AGNIGARH ,   
GUWAHATI, TEZPUR ,   , BAMUNI HILLS,, MAHABHAIRAB TEMPLE, AGNIGARH,  
GUWAHATI, , TEZPUR, , BAMUNI HILLS, MAHABHAIRAB TEMPLE, AGNIGARH
```

**Expected output**

```
GUWAHATI, TEZPUR, BAMUNI HILLS, MAHABHAIRAB TEMPLE, AGNIGARH
```

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace('/\s*(?:,\s*)+/', ', ',$string)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `trim` the `$string` from whitespace and commas using `trim($string, ', \n\r\t\v\x00')` (the chars are the [default `trim` chars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) + a comma) and then use `preg_replace('/\s*(?:,\s*)+/', ', ', ...)`:

```php
<?php

$string = ", , GUWAHATI, TEZPUR, , BAMUNI HILLS, MAHABHAIRAB TEMPLE, AGNIGARH ,   ";
echo preg_replace('/\s*(?:,\s*)+/', ', ', trim($string, ", \n\r\t\v\x00"));
// => GUWAHATI, TEZPUR, BAMUNI HILLS, MAHABHAIRAB TEMPLE, AGNIGARH
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/LAiWX)

The `\s*(?:,\s*)+` pattern matches zero or more whitespace followed with one or more sequences of a comma and zero or more whitespaces. Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iFrzXB/1).

Answer (score 3):

You may use this solution:

```php
$s = preg_replace('/^[,\h]+|\h*(,)(?:\h*,)+\h*|[,\h]+$/m', '$1 ', $s);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqsoMx/1)

**Breakdown:**

- `^[,\h]+`: Match 1+ of comma or spaces after start
- `|`: OR
- `\h*(,)(?:\h*,)+\h*`: Match 2 or more of comma *optionally* separated by spaces. Note that we match a single comma in capture group
- `|`: OR
- `[,\h]+$`: Match 1+ of comma or spaces before end
- `'$1 '`: Is replacement to put captured value of comma followed by a single space